# Custom dispatcher for specific sharded actor

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

Is there any way to assign custom dispatcher for specific sharded actor? I have found example for non sharded actor but not with sharded actor.

Comment: Classic or Typed?

Answer (score 0):

For Typed Cluster Sharding, you would define the dispatcher as part of `Props` and when initializing sharding, you would tell sharding to make the actors incarnating a given type of `Entity` use the specified dispatcher.

In Scala, this could look like:

```scala
val entityProps = Props.empty.withDispatcherFromConfig("config-path-to-dispatcher-definition")
val createBehaviorFn: (EntityContext[MyEntity.Command]) => Behavior[MyEntity.Command] = ???
val typeKey = EntityTypeKey[MyEntity.Command]("my-entity")
val myEntity = Entity(typeKey)(createBehaviorFn).withEntityProps(entityProps)

sharding.init(myEntity)
```

In Classic Cluster Sharding, the broad idea is similar (except you use Classic `Props` instead of Typed `Props`), but it's been too long since I've really used Classic.